# How to do Wikification / Entity Linking on the basis of the EntityMentionsAnnotator?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, dbpedia, named-entity-recognition, wikidata

I am trying to link entity mentions to a knowledge base, for instance DBpedia or Wikidata.

In the end I want to enrich the JSON output with an arbitrary ontology and hereby provide some kind of semantics. But as a first step it should just look something like this:

```
{

    "index": 1,
    "mention": "Barack Obama",
    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
    "characterOffsetEnd": 12,
    "ner": "PERSON",
    "before": "",
    "after": " "
    "uri": "http://dbpedia.org/page/Barack_Obama"

}
```

Is there a way of doing so with the already provided tools of Stanford CoreNLP? I have seen a WikidictAnnotator on GitHub, but unfortunately there is no documentation or whatsoever on what it is and how to use it respectively.

Apart form that, what other possibilities are there? Do I have to use a third-party tool like DBpedia Spotlight in conjunction with the Stanford NE Recognizer in order to realize entity linking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use http://dbpedia.org/sparql api to query dbpedia. e.g.  SELECT distinct ?uri ?label
 WHERE {
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label .
    FILTER regex(str(?label), "Barack Obama", "i")
}

Comment: Your suggested approach is too straightfoward I think. What if there are ambiguous entity mentions, for instance "George Bush"? This could refer to both George Bush sr. and George Bush jr.

I know there are third-party entitiy linking tools that are capable of disambiguation, but is it also possible to do this with CoreNLP? If not, what API or tool should I use in conjunction with CoreNLP?

Comment: I currently need the same thing. It seems that the only solutions for these are expensive APIs, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I am going to answer my own question. Maybe it helps somebody in the future.

I found a framework called AGDISTIS which provides a mentions to knowledge base functionality. It accepts mentions from the EntityMentionsAnnotator and matches them with the according dbpedia resources. You can even use another index apart from dbpedia.

Nevertheless, I would be happy if someone could explain whether and how wikification is possible just with CoreNLP (see WikidictAnnotator).

Comment: WikidictAnnotator will not work. To stick with your example, understand that "Obama" is an ambiguous name: it can either refer to Barack Obama or Michelle Obama or other persons with that name. DBpedia, Wikidata, YAGO, and other KBs store entities, i.e. their IDs. Processing "Obama was the first lady" with a dictionary lookup (the "dict" part in WikidictAnnotator), only "Obama" is recognized as a mention, without knowing which one. To get the Wikidata ID (in this case Q13133), you need the context where the mention "Obama" occurs, something that AGIDISTIS (or AIDA, or Dexter, ...) does.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I was not aware that WikidictAnnotator is just a dictionary lookup. Fortunately, there are frameworks that are able to disambiguate mentions provided by CoreNLP instead of running their own entity/mentions recognition and then disambiguates them.

Answer (score 0):

At [Ambiverse](https://www.ambiverse.com) we have an [entity-linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking) system, which identifies [named entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity) in text. Each entity is linked to its Wikidata Id. The output is a JSON object containing the identified entities and their positions in the input text, plus some useful entity metadata as categories, Wikipedia URL and the linking confidence. The system can be used as an API. To read more about entity-linking or use cases you can check our [blog](https://www.ambiverse.com/blog/).

As an example take the sentence:

> Ma founded Alibaba in Hangzhou with investments from SoftBank and
>   Goldman.

Our system would produce the output below. You can also try it yourself [here](https://www.ambiverse.com/#demo).

```
{
"docId": "1803274355",
"language": "en",
"matches": [
  {
    "charLength": 2,
    "charOffset": 0,
    "text": "Ma",
    "entity": {
      "id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1137062",
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack%20Ma",
      "confidence": 0.24400826614264
    }
  },
  {
    "charLength": 7,
    "charOffset": 11,
    "text": "Alibaba",
    "entity": {
      "id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1359568",
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alibaba%20Group",
      "confidence": 0.89595517818717
    }
  },
  {
    "charLength": 8,
    "charOffset": 22,
    "text": "Hangzhou",
    "entity": {
      "id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q4970",
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangzhou",
      "confidence": 0.92296125433251
    }
  },
  {
    "charLength": 8,
    "charOffset": 53,
    "text": "SoftBank",
    "entity": {
      "id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q201653",
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftBank",
      "confidence": 0.95402181746993
    }
  },
  {
    "charLength": 7,
    "charOffset": 66,
    "text": "Goldman",
    "entity": {
      "id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q193326",
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman%20Sachs",
      "confidence": 0.41802014708618
    }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Your system looks nice. But unfortunately, I need something free and open source.

Comment: When you sign up for the API you get 1,000 requests for free every month.